# Python Use Regex Sub Multiple Times in 1 Pass

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to combine multiple regex statements into one so it can do different subs on a single pass?

```
no_Punct = re.sub('(\w)([?:!.,;-]+)(\s)',r'\1 ',raw)
no_Punct = re.sub('(\s)([-]+)(\s)',r'\1',no_Punct)
```

The input string is 'raw'. I am trying to strip certain punctuation at the ends of words and remove hyphens that are surrounded by a space on each side. Can I combine both of these into one statement?

Given the input of:
This is a sentence! One-fourth equals .25.

Output is:
This is a sentence one fourth equals .25

Comment: can you show some sample input and expected outputs?

Comment: Sample input/output is added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trivially, by just substituting one into the other:

```
no_Punct = re.sub('(\s)([-]+)(\s)', r'\1', re.sub('(\w)([?:!.,;-]+)(\s)', r'\1 ', raw))
```

Although this may also work:

```
no_Punct = re.sub('(?<=\w)[?:!.,;-]+(?=\s)|(?<=\s)-+\s', '', raw)
```

Comment: For the first method you posted, wouldn't that still make two passes? One pass is made to eliminate all punctuation at the end of a word/sentence and then that output is fed into the next sub. That still looks like 2 passes through the whole string. Is that correct?